# Connect logged user with model

Tags: python, django, model

I'm working on small project with Django framework. And as I can implement usage of authentication mechanism, that I can find a solution how to use information about logged user with model I define.
In example. I have model that will store information about QSL cards, and I want to have option that depends on which user is logged, his/her QSL cars will be shown from database.

I search here and in docs.djangoproject.com but without success.

Thanks in advance for any tips or links.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth

Answer (score 0):

If you try,
`user = request.user`
Variable `user` will have currently logged in user object. You can use this `user` to filter some models objects where `user` is foreign key. For e.g `posts = Post.objects.filter(user=request.user)`. If you want to get any specific user information, for e.g username. You can try `username = request.user.username`